# NTLM Authentication Failed, the server finally response "401", but not "200 OK"

Tags: ntlm

I'm using Node.js to connect to Server with NTLM Authentication. As the NTLM protocol steps below(refer: http://www.innovation.ch/personal/ronald/ntlm.html).

```
1: C  --> S   GET ...

2: C <--  S   401 Unauthorized
              WWW-Authenticate: NTLM

3: C  --> S   GET ...
              Authorization: NTLM <base64-encoded type-1-message>

4: C <--  S   401 Unauthorized
              WWW-Authenticate: NTLM <base64-encoded type-2-message>

5: C  --> S   GET ...
              Authorization: NTLM <base64-encoded type-3-message>

6: C <--  S   200 Ok
```

the 1-5 step works fine, but in the 6th step, the server didn't return me with 200 OK, but returned me with status code 401, and with headers:

HEADS: {

```
   'content-type': 'text/html',
   server: 'Microsoft-IIS/8.0',
   'www-authenticate': 'Negotiate, NTLM',
   'x-powered-by': 'ASP.NET',
   date: 'Sat, 12 Jul 2014 06:44:25 GMT',
   'content-length': '1293'
```

}

Is there anything wrong? Could you help me? Why doesn't it return 200 OK and correct response body? Thanks very much

Comment: Can you provide us the 1293-byte content?

Comment: Hi, Alireza. It's the html 401 page. The body content is:<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">...<title>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</title>...</body></html>

Comment: Can you double-check all of these? the password hashing, the character-encoding and base-64 encoding? You can use Fiddler to check the step-5 content.

Comment: And also check the domain-name and user name

Comment: Hi, Alireza. I used IE 8 to test it. And I think the Authorization value are generated by the browser(the browser will pop-up dialog to input mailbox and password.). Is there possible that these Authorization value are wrong?

Comment: OK, so if the browser does the negotiation there is just the problem of server authentication. I now need the full server response. The details may help.

Comment: Hi，Alireza. I've found the answer. Please see my comment blow. Thanks:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all.

I found the answer finally. I use this ntlm module(https://www.npmjs.org/package/ntlm) to do the ntlm Authentication. And it doesn't work because I use wrong username. I found it from debug log and you can also found this info in the adfs machine's event view(it will have error info). I'm sorry for the stupid mistake, but not bad now I know ntlm well. Thanks Alireza. Thanks all:-)

Comment: Thanks for the module link! What debug log did you find this in? I'm experiencing the same exact thing you are, but am fairly certain my credentials are correct (they work when I visit site through browser, but request is failing), and am not seeing any output other than the 401 error. Thanks!